# Problems Configuring apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apache2.4

I'm trying to set up a machine to run php with ubuntu 12.04, I have
already installed apache2, however when I try restart, I got the following error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 212 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_default.load: Can not load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so: can not open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Action 'configtest' failed.

I tried to find this `mod_authz_default.so` file and it does not exist, and I also didn't find this file on the internet to download. Can you please help me?

Comment: You should not install arbitrary files from the internet! You have no way to control what you are actually installing that way! This is what the software management systems in Linux based systems are for.

Comment: May we know how you installed that apache http server? This sounds like a very strange situation, like an unresolved dependency which is very unlikely. Could it be that you also installed apache in such a "wild" manner, by just downloading something from the internet?

Answer (score 2):

Comment out line 212 and try configtest. I think `mod_authz_default` has been removed  in apache 2.4. You might be using old apache conf.